# What happens if a defender blocks a non-ball carrier?

Tags: rules, american-football

While an offensive player can block a defensive player, the defense can only block or tackle the ball-carrier. What foul (if any) is committed if a defensive player blocks a non-ball carrier?

Comment: I don't know all of the specifics, but I do know that it depends on the situation.  Illegal Contact comes to mind, as do Pass Interference and Holding.